# Is ConTeXt a good choice for creating a nice large catalog?

Tags: context, book-design, printing

I only know a little of ConTeXt but I was wondering if it would be a good idea to use ConTeXt for creating a large catalog containing hundreds of books with a three column layout inside. I was thinking that context would be easier to add products and remove products and their positions on each page would be handled automatically based on my settings. This would be better than using InDesign, Scribus, or Office Publisher, etc. and having to manually create each page and insert and space out each product, while trying to fit as many on a page and later having to manually shift over books to add or the opposite to remove books. My fear is that ConTeXt is not capable of doing what I want or that it would take too much work to get it the way I want in order for it to be worth it.

**Summary:** using design software would require to much manual work to update and change the catalog. I'm curious if ConTeXt is worth using for such a project or if I should find something else.

**Example:** here's a picture inside the old catalog. I would like the new to look similar:

[image: This is picture of the inside of the old catalog]

Comment: I don't use ConTeXt so I can't say but I would create a bibliographical database of the books (a `.bib` file) and then use `biblatex` and `biber` to sort the entries and create the formatted catalogue. `.bib` files are meant to hold this sort of information, `biber` is designed to parse such files, extracting and sorting the entries, and `biblatex` is designed to control the formatting on a fine-grained basis. Of course, 3-column format is not a standard style (that I know of) but the beauty of `biblatex` is that it is configurable through regular LaTeX code.

Comment: @cfr, am I able to to have long descriptions, and images I want displayed stored in a .bib file?

Comment: Descriptions, yes. No idea about images. Well, you can't store images in a `.bib` file any more than you can store them in ConTeXt code so I guess you mean can you have commands to include them from other files? That I'm not sure about.

Comment: I have a hard time understanding what you want. Can you give an example of the content.

Comment: @Aditya, I added a picture to the question.

Comment: I'll be happy to edit the question if there is something else your confused about.

Comment: Hmm.. I had added a comment, but it did not appear. This should be easy to do in both LaTeX and ConTeXt. If I were doing this, I would store all the data in an XML file, and use ConTeXt Lua Documents to generate the appropriate TeX commands. That takes some time to set up, but is more robust in the long run. I'll try to post ConTeXt code that generates the layout that you want.

Comment: You should also check out the open source software by @topskip that uses luatex + XML to generate product catalogs.

Comment: I was thinking that XML would be a good format to store the information but I was having trouble finding information on that. I'll look into what you've mentioned. Thanks!

Answer (score 4):

Absolutely. I have prepared couple of exhibition catalogues in ConTeXt and really enjoyed using it. It shouldn't be too difficult to define a float like the one in the image which could be used in conjunction with [columns or columnsets](http://wiki.contextgarden.net/Columns#Overview). It looks like your data are coming from a database so perhaps it might be useful to output them in xml and feed it into ConTeXt.

Comment: Hello, is there some samples you can share?

Comment: Sadly not. As I was comfortable with XSLT I simply generated the body of my ConTeXt source from XML, adding preamble,  but You can process XML directly in ConTeXt.